# Time elapsed with condition in data.table

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, subset

My objective is to take the difference in minutes between first and last timestamp by `id` where timestamps are spaced 10 minutes apart.  Standalone timestamps should be assigned `10`.  If there is a sequence of timestamps, then the difference in time should equal the last in the sequence - first in the sequence.  For example:

```
> test
   id           timestamp
1   1 2018-01-02 00:40:00
2   1 2018-01-02 00:50:00
4   1 2018-01-02 01:10:00
5   1 2018-01-02 01:20:00
6   1 2018-01-02 01:30:00
7   1 2018-01-02 02:00:00
8   2 2018-01-02 01:50:00
9   2 2018-01-02 02:00:00
10  2 2018-01-02 02:10:00
11  2 2018-01-02 02:20:00
12  2 2018-01-02 02:30:00
13  2 2018-01-02 02:40:00
14  2 2018-01-02 03:10:00
15  2 2018-01-02 03:20:00
```

Should produce an output of:

```
> output
  id                                    period elapsed
1  1 2018-01-02 00:40:00 - 2018-01-02 00:50:00      10
2  1 2018-01-02 01:10:00 - 2018-01-02 01:30:00      20
3  1                       2018-01-02 02:00:00      10
4  2 2018-01-02 01:50:00 - 2018-01-02 02:40:00      50
5  2 2018-01-02 03:10:00 - 2018-01-02 03:20:00      10
```

Any suggestions with `data.table` or `dplyr` would be appreciated.  I'm guessing the pseudocode would look something like this

```
 setDT(teset)
    test[, .(elapsed := ifelse(difftime(last_timestamp, first_timestamp) > 10, difftime(last_timestamp, first_timestamp), 10) .(period := paste(first_timestamp, "-", last_timestamp)), by = id]
```

Here is the sample dataset:

```
   > dput(test)
structure(list(id = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2), timestamp = structure(c(1514875200, 1514875800, 1514877000, 
1514877600, 1514878200, 1514880000, 1514879400, 1514880000, 1514880600, 
1514881200, 1514881800, 1514882400, 1514884200, 1514884800), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "America/Chicago")), .Names = c("id", "timestamp"
), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 
13L, 14L, 15L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Are you saying that each pair of two should be considered a start and an end?

Comment: Not each pair of two.  A pair should be the start of a sequence of intervals spaced 10 minutes apart and the end of that sequence.

Comment: Can you explain what is "last timestamp by `id`". You use different ones

Comment: Sequences should be grouped by id, please see the output.  For example, if if there is more than 10 minutes between two timestamps, they should be treated as separate sequences.  Standalone timestamps should then be assigned a 10, does that make sense?  Timestamp `7   1 2018-01-02 02:00:00` for example is a standalone timestamp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make a counter for the differences being `> 10` mins, then group:

```
setDT(test)
test[, grp := cumsum(c(0,diff(timestamp)) > 10) , by=id]
test[,
  .(
     period  = paste(timestamp[1], timestamp[.N], sep=" - "),
     elapsed = difftime(timestamp[.N], timestamp[1], units="mins")
   ),
  by=.(id,grp)
]

#   id grp                                    period elapsed
#1:  1   0 2018-01-02 00:40:00 - 2018-01-02 00:50:00 10 mins
#2:  1   1 2018-01-02 01:10:00 - 2018-01-02 01:30:00 20 mins
#3:  1   2 2018-01-02 02:00:00 - 2018-01-02 02:00:00  0 mins
#4:  2   0 2018-01-02 01:50:00 - 2018-01-02 02:40:00 50 mins
#5:  2   1 2018-01-02 03:10:00 - 2018-01-02 03:20:00 10 mins
```

Comment: thank you! minutes should be specified somewhere for the units of `elapsed`, right? because on a larger dataset the output in `elapsed` can be minutes or hours with the code above

Comment: @the_darkside - yes, you're right - I will edit to force to mins via `difftime`

Comment: Or I think the `grp` can be directly used in the `by` if the original data structure not want to be changed `setDT(test)[, .(period  = paste(timestamp[1], timestamp[.N], sep=" - "),
      elapsed = difftime(timestamp[.N], timestamp[1], units="mins")
    ), by = .(id, grp = cumsum(c(0,diff(timestamp)) > 10))]`